# What about img blob data affect for seo & client performance

Tags: seo, images, performance, optimization, load-time

in simple cms project with some picture lower 1mb , save all image as blob data in database (exp: sqlite) is good idea for files management...

How does this affect SEO? for example on: pageload web client performance

i don't try this but i know good idea for file management.

Answer (score 1):

SEO doesnt care where you save the images.  What matters is how fast you can retrieve them.  And the speed depends on your provider, your plan, your code, size of images etc.

Personally I would store them as files.  It would be easier to edit or replace them.  And sqlite is not exactly a high performance database.

Comment: Agree with everything in your answer except the bit about "sqlite is not exactly a high performance database" to the degree it is relevant to this question - https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems are mildly useful in supporting my position.